# $f \sim e^u/u$ as $u \to +\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, asymptotics

I am trying to find a "simple" (for example a function $f$ that has a nice antiderivative) function $f$ such that :
$$f \sim \frac{e^u}{u} \text{as } u \to +\infty$$

I have rewritten $e^{u-\ln(u)}$ yet it doesn't help, because finding $g$ such that : $g \sim \ln(u)$ is hard, because the series expansion of $\ln(u)$ has term of different sign...

Comment: $\frac{e^{u-\sqrt{u}}}{u}$, $e^u\frac{u}{u^2+1}$, etc?

Comment: How about $$f = \dfrac{d}{du} \left( \frac{e^u}{u}\right) = \frac{e^u}{u} - \frac{e^u}{u^2} $$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael has the right idea. [Related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_potential).

Comment: @K.defaoite's last idea is related to [this](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/norm-dist-bounds/), which has been the subject of multiple questions here.